# Keybind to fold function or class in Sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3, key-bindings

Is there a keybind to press the little fold arrow that appears before a function or class?

[image]

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Added editor to question title, and tag. Sorry

Comment: Not directly, but you can fold the selection with a key press (`shift+ctrl+[` or `command+alt+[`) and you can press the key to expand the selection to the current indent level (`shift+ctrl+j` or `command+shift+j`) 1 or more times to select what you want folded. Other than that some plugin code would be needed (e.g. Fold Python on PackageControl.io perhaps).

Answer (score 2):

Goto EDIT > Code Folding. It will show you all the command for Sublime Text.

Comment: This does not what I'm looking for. It only enables me to fold *all* of the functions. I just want to fold one fucntion. To select all text of the function and then fold the selected text takes ages I just want to press the fold arrow without having to move my hand to the mouse.

Comment: Those are the only options bundled with Sublime. You might be able to find a good package to help. [This maybe](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SyntaxFold)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is. What you can do though is this:

```
def my_func():
     # put your cursor wherever you want on a line that has this level of indentation (here 1)
    """my doc"""
    print('this is') # you can put it here
    print('some code that is going to') # or here
    print('folded!')
    if nb % 2 == 0:
        print('this is an even number') # but not here!
```

press `ctrl+shift+[`. It going to automatically select the indentation (so your function's content), and fold it up.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @math2001's answer, `ctrl+shift+l` will fold a class or function

This only works when the cursor is below the indentation you want to fold.

Ie. you want to fold functionB, the cursor must be on a line above or below functionB's braces

```
functionA() {
    functionB() { //I will fold under A. Don't fold here
        //Fold me
        functionC() { //Fold me
        } //Fold me
    } //Fold me
}
```